# Changing color in a shape inside a layer-list programmatically

Tags: android, shapes, android-drawable, layerdrawable

I am trying to change programmatically the color of the **selectable_kachel_shape**. Here is the xml file:

**kachel_ticked_style.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


    <item>
        <shape
            android:id="@+id/selectable_kachel_shape"
            android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke
                android:width="5dp"
                android:color="@color/headrbar_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="120%"
            android:pivotY="100%"
            android:toDegrees="45" >
            <shape android:shape="line" >
                <stroke
                    android:width="40dp"
                    android:color="@color/headrbar_color" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="top|right"
            android:src="@drawable/selectable_tiles_check" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

I am calling inside a Fragment the following code

```
LayerDrawable layers = (LayerDrawable)  this.getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.kachel_ticked_style);

GradientDrawable shape = (GradientDrawable) (layers.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.selectable_kachel_shape));
                       shape.setColor(this.getActivity().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_dark);
```

1.Why am I geting a NullPointerException in **shape.setColor**?

2.How would it be possible to change the color inside a shape, that is inside a layer list, programmatically?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Ok I found the answer, I just had to put the id of the shape inside the item not in the shape
**kachel_ticked_style.xml**:

```
<item 
    android:id="@+id/selectable_kachel_shape">
        <shape
             android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke
                android:width="5dp"
                android:color="@color/headrbar_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>
```

And then you can change either the color of the shape calling **shape.setColor** or the color of the stroke calling **shape.setStroke(strokeWidth,strokeColor)**

Comment: But am having the same problem.This doesnt work for me

Comment: Well @jincyabraham you can get the view then its background drawable then get the shape as a gradiendrawable as in here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636412/change-shape-solid-color-at-runtime-inside-drawable-xml-used-as-background)

Comment: Can you please show what steps you did to acquire the the shape object, it is unclear.

Comment: This works for a GradientDrawable, but not for a RotateDrawable which color I try to define at runtime. Any ideas?