# how to Change shape solid color at runtime inside Drawable xml

Tags: android, xml, layer-list

I would like to change solid color in my drawable pragmatically.

source:

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705992/changing-color-in-a-shape-inside-a-layer-list-programmatically)

@drawable/rightmenu_categories_title :

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/drawable_main_title_details_content_an_item"
    >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">

        <solid android:color="#f4262b"/>
        <corners android:topLeftRadius="4dp"/>

    </shape>

</item>
```

my layout :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/lay_rel_title_categories_rightmenucontents" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_view_title_detalis_content_an_item" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/str_title_categories_rightmenu"
        android:background="@drawable/rightmenu_categories_title"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

```
private void setColorOnTitleDetailContentAnItem(int which){
    View v = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txt_view_title_detalis_content_an_item);

    LayerDrawable bgDrawable = (LayerDrawable)v.getBackground();
    final GradientDrawable shape = (GradientDrawable)  bgDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.drawable_main_title_details_content_an_item);
    shape.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}
```

but I get follow errors :

```
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 02-01 19:10:05.326:
> E/AndroidRuntime(23755):  at
> ....ContentAnItem.setColorOnTitleDetailContentAnItem(ContentAnItem.java:241)
> 02-01 19:10:05.326: E/AndroidRuntime(23755):  at
> ....ContentAnItem.findViewsById(ContentAnItem.java:227)
```

on 241 line :

```
LayerDrawable bgDrawable = (LayerDrawable)v.getBackground();
```

on 227 line,my function is called .

---

**solved :**

in fragment class I must using rootView:

```
  View v = rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_view_title_detalis_content_an_item);
```