# Programmatically change color of shape in layer list

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-xml

How can I programmatically change the color (`#000000`) of a shape in a layer list?

Here is my layer list:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#000000" /> // CHANGE THIS COLOR
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/bg" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705992/changing-color-in-a-shape-inside-a-layer-list-programmatically

Comment: Suhail Mehta gave a detail answer. And also explain how to set single item shape color. It should be accepted Answer

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First of all you need to assign id to you `layer-list` item.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- First assign id to the list item-->
    <item  android:id="@+id/your_shape">  
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#000000" /> 
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/bg" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Then get your shape by id.

```
LayerDrawable shape = (LayerDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_shape)
```

And you can change the color of your shape by calling

```
shape.setColor(Color.Black); // changing to black color
```

**EDIT**

As `getDrawable()` has been deprecated. Use the following line of code.

```
LayerDrawable shape = (LayerDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(YourActivity.this,R.drawable.your_shape)
```

Comment: `getDrawable()` is deprecated.

Comment: for me it works better if I get the layerlist with getBackground on the widget that has it instead of geetting it from resources

Comment: This solution didn't work for me, your_shape is an id and not a drawable. Suhail's answer works for me.

Comment: LayerDrawable drawableFile = (LayerDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.drawable_file_name);
GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable) drawableFile.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id. your_shape);

Answer (score 77):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/gradientDrawble"> // Give id
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#000000" /> // CHANGE THIS COLOR
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/bg" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Then in you code just add

```
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) getResources()
            .getDrawable(R.drawable.my_drawable);
GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable) layerDrawable
            .findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.gradientDrawble);
gradientDrawable.setColor(color); // change color
```

**Update Oct-2016**

`getDrawable()` is now deprecated, you should use `ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, color)` instead.

Beside, if you get the `LayerDrawable` by `findDrawableByLayerId()`, then you had to call `view.setBackground(layerDrawable)` for this to take effect. Alternatively, instantiating the `layerDrawable` by `view.getBackground()` also worked.

Comment: `getDrawable()` is deprecated. Is there another way?

Comment: @user Just use ContextCompat.getDrawable()

Comment: Any reason why this only works when I restart my Activity (for example, using `Instant Run`)?

Comment: This is the correct answer. Another option is `gradientDrawable.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);` where `color` is a resolved color, for example `Color.BLACK`

Answer (score 19):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/outer">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval">
            <size android:height="40dp" android:width="40dp"/>
            <padding android:top="3dp" android:bottom="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:left="3dp"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#ffffff"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@+id/middle">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval">
            <size android:height="40dp" android:width="40dp"/>
            <padding android:top="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:left="2dp"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="#ffffff"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@+id/inner">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval">
            <size android:height="40dp" android:width="40dp"/>
            <solid
                android:color="#ffffff"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Find your view

```
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) yourView.getBackground();
GradientDrawable outer = (GradientDrawable) layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.outer);
GradientDrawable middle = (GradientDrawable) layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.middle);
GradientDrawable inner = (GradientDrawable) layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.inner);
```

Set color

```
outer.setColor(Color.parseColor(#000000));
inner.setColor(Color.parseColor(#FFFFFF));
```

Comment: This is the one that worked for me. (And I had tried the two other solutions.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the drawable or background of the view and set it as follows.

```
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) view.getDrawable(); //view.getBackground()
GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable) layerDrawable
                .findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.layer_list_item_id);
gradientDrawable.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorPrimary));
```