# Programmatically change the color of a shape in a layer-list for a button with text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-xml

I'm trying to create a circle button with text and an image. I want to add it programmatically in my activity and change the background color at the same time.

Following is working fine, but has not image. 
The button_round.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false"
          android:id="@+id/button_round_oval">
        <shape android:shape="oval"
            android:id="@+id/button_round_oval_shape">
            <solid android:color="#52a0e8"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#3280c8"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

The activity:

```
...
Button b = new Button(this);
...
b.setText(myText);
b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_round); //the drawable above
GradientDrawable bgShape = (GradientDrawable)b.getBackground().getCurrent();
bgShape.setColor(Color.parseColor("#0000FF"));
...
```

I searched for a solution but couldn't get it working (e.g. here: [Programmatically change color of shape in layer list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163918/programmatically-change-color-of-shape-in-layer-list/32163993)).

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false"
          android:id="@+id/button_round_oval">
        <layer-list 
            android:id="@+id/button_round_oval_layer">
            <item 
                android:id="@+id/button_round_oval_item">
                <shape 
                    android:shape="oval"
                    android:id="@+id/button_round_oval_shape">
                    <solid android:color="#52a0e8"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <bitmap 
                    android:gravity="center" 
                    android:src="@drawable/stars_one" />
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#3280c8"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

And in the activity I have tried for example this:

```
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.button_round);
GradientDrawable bgShape = (GradientDrawable) layerDrawable
                    .findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.button_round_oval_item);
bgShape.setColor(Color.parseColor("#0000FF"));
```

But in this case I'm getting an error message:

```
android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable
```

The 2nd question is (when this is working), how to change the background color of the state_pressed as well.

Thanks in advance!