# How to change or fill color of shape inside layer-list

Tags: android, android-layout, layer-list

I have tried using the below solution but it didn't worked

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163918/programmatically-change-color-of-shape-in-layer-list

Here is my code...

**Rolling.java**

```
    package com.example.app1;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Rolling extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LayerDrawable layerDrawable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rolling);

        LayerDrawable shape = (LayerDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(Rolling.this,R.drawable.dice1);
     /*   GradientDrawable outer = (GradientDrawable) layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.drawable.dice1);
        outer.setColor(Color.BLACK);*/
        shape.setTint(Color.BLUE);

    }
}
```

**activity_rolling.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Rolling">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/dice1" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**dice1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingRight="50dp" android:paddingLeft="50dp">
    <!-- Larger blue circle -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/dice1"
        android:bottom="214dp"
        android:top="214dp"
        android:left="100dp"
        android:right="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:tileMode="repeat"
        >
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff207d94" />
            <padding android:left="2dp"
                android:top="2dp"
                android:right="2dp"
                android:bottom="2dp" />
            <size android:width="100dp" android:height="100dp"/>
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
   
</layer-list>
```

So I want to change the color of square shape programmatically So how can I achieve that?

Comment: You could use ColorFilter.

Answer (score 0):

inside `Rolling extends AppCompatActivity` you are obtaining new `LayerDrawable` called `shape`, but this is "new instance" of this image, you have to set it for your `ImageView` then

```
ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
iv.setImageDrawable(shape);
```

resources are "untouchable" - if you obtain some drawable programmaticaly and make some changes (e.g. set color filter or tint) this doesn't mean that resource/drawable changed. any other further `getDrawable` or `app:srcCompat` will fetch image as original without your changes

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so I'll post this as an answer.
You could try one of these.

```
shape.setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

or

```
shape.setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN);
```

Don't forget to invalidate/refresh the drawable.

```
shape.invalidate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code, to change the solid and stroke color of the drawable.

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
GradientDrawable imageViewDrawable = (GradientDrawable) imageView.getBackground();
imageViewDrawable.setStroke(<border_width_int>, <border_color>)
imageViewDrawable.setColor(<btn_color>)
```

Comment: I am getting this error when I tried this... java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.setColor(int)' on a null object reference