# How to change Remote view Background in runtime

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, drawable

I am trying to change the remote view background in runtime, I am using drawable xml to show customize notification.

**custom_notification.xml**

```
 android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
    android:layout_height="65sp"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:drawableLeft="@id/layout"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
         android:textSize="12sp"
        style="Custom Notification Title" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Drawable-->layout_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item android:id="@+id/shape">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke  android:width="3dip" />
    <corners android:radius="10dip" />
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />

</shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Inside the activity

```
   View v = findViewById(R.id.layout);
             LayerDrawable bgDrawable = (LayerDrawable)v.getBackground();
             final GradientDrawable shape = (GradientDrawable)   bgDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.shape);
if(highstatus){
shape.setColor(R.color.highStatus);
}
```

Please correct if am wrong. After trying to set shape color.  am getting error **"Unfortunately, App has been stopped"** While receiving the notification

Comment: Please post the logcat output.

Comment: 07-03 11:14:35.959: E/AndroidRuntime(28112): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[GCMIntentService-GCMIntentService-1]

Comment: @ShivamVerma I am receiving notification before, if i revert it back i will get. The problem is trying to customize the drawable bg color

Comment: Please add the relevant part of the logcat output by editing the answer. It'll contain the Exception that was generated.

Comment: You are trying to get a reference to a RemoteViews view with findViewById? That method is not available.