# How to change the solid color programmatically of a shape in Android?

Tags: android, shapes, android-imagebutton

I'm trying to change the `solid` color of a `shape` in my `Fragment`.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/icon_circle_background">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            ...>
            <solid android:color="@color/md_cyan_400"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        ...
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I can't seem to access it from my code and I already have tried the following answers on stack overflow:

[Set android shape color programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823451/set-android-shape-color-programmatically)

[How to change shape color dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164630/how-to-change-shape-color-dynamically)

[Change shape solid color at runtime inside Drawable xml used as background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636412/change-shape-solid-color-at-runtime-inside-drawable-xml-used-as-background)

None of these worked or were pretty outdated.

Fragment where I try to change the color:

```
public class GameFragment extends Fragment {
    private Theme currentTheme;
    private Circle currentCircle;
    private int currentOrganisationId;
    private List<Card> circleCards;
    private List<ImageButton> circleButtons;
    private int viewHeight;
    private int viewWidth;
    private int marginCard;
    private int[] tableStarts;
    private RelativeLayout background;
    private ViewTreeObserver vto;

    public GameFragment() {
        circleCards = new ArrayList<>();
        circleButtons = new ArrayList<>();
        tableStarts = new int[9];
    }

    //...

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game, container, false);
        ...
        background = setBackground(rootView);
        circleCards = currentCircle.getCards();

        return rootView;
    }

    //...

    private void drawCards() {
        circleButtons = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Card card : circleCards) {
            ImageButton myImageButton = new ImageButton(this.getContext()); //generate ImageButton
            myImageButton.setId(card.getCardId()); //Set Id of button
            myImageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle_card_icon);

            //set random color to shape
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `were pretty outdated` mean? They should work just fine.

Comment: @Bob Malooga, tried it, still gives me this https://goo.gl/fXL4Pe code: http://pastebin.com/KqNNTDnU

Answer (score 3):

use this:

```
GradientDrawable bgShape = (GradientDrawable)view.getBackground().getCurrent();
bgShape.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

.getCurrent give the selected drawable layerlist

use this it will not throw java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable exception.

it works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.layout_id);
LayerDrawable shape= (LayerDrawable)v.getBackground();
shape.setColor(Color.Black);
```