# Change xml drawable shape color as src programmatically

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable, xml-drawable

Having trouble with changing the color of a shape in a drawable XML.

I have this xml drawable file (which creates 3 circles one inside the other):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval"
        android:id="@+id/card_layer1">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <size
            android:width="5dp"
            android:height="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:top="2dp" android:left="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:bottom="2dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval"
        android:id="@+id/card_layer2">
        <solid android:color="#ff0000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <size
            android:width="5dp"
            android:height="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:top="4dp" android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp" android:bottom="4dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval"
        android:id="@+id/card_layer3">
        <solid android:color="#ffffff"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <size
            android:width="5dp"
            android:height="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

I want to be able to change programmatically the color of each layer of these shapes.

I found this answer: [Change shape's color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16637696/6451874), but it doesn't work well for me because it changes the `background` attribute, and I am using the `src` attribute so I think I need a different solution.

Basically, I need to find a way to do something that will get me the `src` of a view and not the background:

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.layout_id);

LayerDrawable bgDrawable = (LayerDrawable)v.getBackground(); // get src and not background
```

But, I couldn't find anything that would do that..

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: perhap look into color filters http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114420/applying-colorfilter-to-imageview-with-shapeddrawable

Comment: so dont call `View#getBackground` but call `ImageView#getDrawable`

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work for me.. I want to set the color of different layers all the time, and that doesn't do the job.. Any further ideas??

Comment: read `android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable` documentation

Comment: @pskink still not working, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41433144/changing-android-drawable-layers-not-working

Comment: try Mode.SRC instead